# MySite as the Homepage

Tags: 2013, mysite, mysites

Is it possible to set the user's homepage as their customized mysite profile?

I have a single site collection with the entry level site as our main intranet page. So when a user puts in http://hqsharepoint/ they get to the main intranet page.

Now we're wanting to set the start site to the mysite profile. Is the best way to do this with a redirect? Do I need to move the top-level site and its contents to a subsite and then set hqsharepoint to redirect to http://hqsharepoint/my/ ?

Am I on the right track? Has anyone else tried to set the user profile mysite page as the homepage?

Thanks for any insight or assistance!

Comment: Has anyone answered this question? I would like to do the same thing....use mysite as everyone's homepage.

Comment: Do you have access to the Group Policy Preference settings? If you do, you could configure a GPO to specify http://hqsharepoint/my/ as the start page.

Comment: Thanks for the replies! This is still unanswered. @Kelvin: This is a good idea, but we don't want the mysite profile to be the homepage of their browser. We just want it to be the first page they see when "going to sharepoint". The solution we're leaning towards is to just push out a shortcut to http://hqsharepoint/my/ on everyone's desktop labeled "Sharepoint".